# Can't add view infront of modal controller's view

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog

I have a modally presented view controller and I want to push a modal view on top of it. This should be simple to do, but I've missed something :)

The modally presented view controller doesn't cover the whole screen (it uses custom presentation) so I can't just add my view on top of that. But when I try to add my view to either the presenting view controller, or just onto `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.rootViewController.view` I get a very strange result.

I've tried this using the default modal presentation an it still behaves in the same way, so I don't believe it's my custom presentation causing this.

Here is the exploded view from Xcode - with the overlay at the correct position front and center.

[image: Exploded Xcode interface view]

And here is the simulator at the time this interface was snapshotted.

[image: Simulator showing total lack of alert view]

Does anyone know why the alert view (which is clearly at the top of the stack looking in Xcode) doesn't appear?

NB: I'm pretty confident that the exploded view in Xcode is correct because it matches up with the output from `po [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] view] recursiveDescription]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to `present` some vc in your current and in other view controllers first.

```
    ... // your view controller 
    present(/* your alert view controller */, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For example, it should show a empty vc like below. See if you can `present` any vc normally. If yes, it might be your alert view controller problem.

```
    ... // your view controller 
    let vc = UIViewController()
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    ... // presented a black screen, it works
```